# Probability of a streak in binomial distribution

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, binomial-distribution

Question: Suppose that a coin with a 0.7 chance of getting heads is tossed 100 times. Let **X**
be the number of heads obtained. What is the probability of obtaining a streak of at least 15 consecutive heads in the 100 tosses?

I'm not quite sure how to begin with this problem. Am I missing a general formula for this type of problem?

Comment: Not really. In this case we are dealing with tossing a coin 100 times. In the suggested post, they are flipping 10,000 coins

Comment: I am not asking if you think that solution is applicable.  I am *telling* you that it is.  Your numbers may be different, but the method of solution is the same, and by taking the time to understand how that solution works, all you would need to do is substitute your numbers into the formula.

Comment: I should also clarify that while that question is different, ignore it, because the answer I provided applies to *your* question.